# Optimizing aggregation on MySQL Table with 850 million rows

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have a query that I'm using to summarize via aggregations.

The table is called 'connections' and has about 843 million rows.

```
CREATE TABLE `connections` (
  `app_id` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_started_dt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `device` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `os` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firmware` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `app_id` (`bid`),
  KEY `time_started_dt` (`time_started_dt`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When I try to run a query, such as the one below, it takes over 10 hours and I end up killing it. Does anyone see any mistakes that I'm making, of have any suggestions as to how I could optimize the query?

```
SELECT
app_id,
MAX(time_started_dt),
MIN(time_started_dt),
COUNT(*)
FROM
connections
GROUP BY
app_id
```

Comment: There is no index on `app_id`?

Comment: might include time_started_dt in that index, but app_id is clearly critical.

Comment: @juergen d i actually did have an index on 'app_id' ...bid was a typo.

Comment: In the future please stay put after asking. Normally a questions gets answered in minutes. And if we have to wait 50 minutes for such info you will probably not get much attention any more after correcting that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a composite index on `(app_id, time_started_dt)`:

```
ALTER TABLE connections ADD INDEX(app_id, time_started_dt)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get that query to perform, you really need a suitable covering index, with `app_id` as the leading column, e.g.

```
CREATE INDEX `connections_IX1` ON `connections` (`app_id`,` time_start_dt`);
```

NOTE: creating the index may take hours, and the operation will prevent insert/update/delete to the table while it is running.

An EXPLAIN will show the proposed execution plan for your query. With the covering index in place, you'll see "Using index" in the plan.  (A "covering index" is an index that can be used by MySQL to satisfy a query without having to access the underlying table. That is, the query can be satisfied entirely from the index.)

With the large number of rows in this table, you may also want to consider partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your query on randomly generated data (around 1 million rows). Adding PRIMATY KEY will improve performance of your query by 10%.
As already suggested by other people composite index should be added to the table. Index time_started_dt is useless.

```
CREATE TABLE `connections` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `app_id` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_started_dt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `device` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `os` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firmware` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `composite_idx` (`app_id`,`time_started_dt`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```